# How can I write this code to achieve the same result but with only one foreach statement?

Tags: php, foreach

```
$json = '[
    {
        "class1":
        {
            "function1":"return \"$a<b>$b</b>!\";"
        }
    },
    {
        "class2":
        {
            "function2":"return $b;",
            "function3":"return $c;"
        }
    }
]';
$decoded_classes = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($decoded_classes as $class)
{
    $class_name = key($class);
    if (is_array($class[$class_name]))
    {
        foreach($class[$class_name] as $function)
        {
            $function_name = key($class[$class_name]);
            $stack[$class_name][$function_name] = create_function($arr,$function);
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        foreach($class as $function)
        {
            $c_name = key($class);
            $stack[$c_name] = create_function($arr,$function);
        }
    }
}
return $stack;
```

I need that this code will execute the same result but with only one `foreach`. How can i do that?

Comment: What's the constraint that makes you "need" to do it with only one `foreach`? Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's difficult to guess.

Comment: I have a array of php codes that i need to convert to functions. Basically the code will create functions inside a array and resturn them as variable

Comment: creating functions like this on the fly?! One would say you need to refactor your code so this isnt the case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating the JSON to... let's say "PHPON", you get:

```
$decoded_classes = Array(
    Array(
        "class1"=>Array(
            "function1"=>'return "$a<b>$b</b>!";'
        )
    )
    Array(
        "class2"=>Array(
            "function2"=>'return $b;',
            "function3"=>'return $c;'
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see, your structure isn't exactly the most efficient. You basically have one too many levels.

Restructure the JSON like this:

```
{     
    "class1": {     
        "function1":"return \"$a<b>$b</b>!\";"
    },
    "class2": {     
        "function2":"return $b;",
        "function3":"return $c;"
    }
}
```

In this way, the "PHPON" is:

```
$decoded_classes = Array(
    "class1"=>Array(
        "function1"=>'return "$a<b>$b</b>!";'
    )
    "class2"=>Array(
        "function2"=>'return $b;',
        "function3"=>'return $c;'
    )
);
```

Now you don't even need to loop at all. Accessing `$decoded_classes['class1']['function1']` will give you that code. The only thing you have to do is convert those strings into callable functions, like so:

```
array_walk_recursive($decoded_classes,function(&$f) {$f = create_function($arr,$f);});
```

I can't help but notice you didn't define `$arr` anywhere in your code. You'll have to specify `$arr` correctly for this to work.